# How to create three different indexes within a same Microsoft Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

Sorry for this, probably, simple question. I'm creating a word document for which I have to add three different indexes: (1) Figures, (2) Tables and (3) Content (in this order). So far, I have been able to create the Figure's index, but have been unable to get any further. I have tried everything I found on the internet (except separating my document into different chapters and add a summary to each one), but each time, Word asks me if I want to upgrade the existing (Figures) index (even if I'm using a different tag for Tables), yielding only two possibilities: accept or reject. When I click "accept" the table remains the same, that is, only with the figures' info, without including the "Tables" ones. Any suggestion?

Comment: See my response. I've provided some web resources but it would help if I had more information about how you are trying to do this.

Comment: A sample document (excerpt from your problem document with at least a couple of tables and figures and the three indices you are trying to create) would help. You can save such a document on OneDrive or DropBox and post a link in an edit to your question. Here is an article explaining how to create such a sample without sharing confidential or proprietary information. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/why-a-sample-file-is-important-for-troubleshooting/9441ae3c-1e92-41c6-9a1f-5b377b08e5a5?tm=1619027698258

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You will find on-line documentation for these under "Table of Contents" and "Table of Figures," not under "Index."*

### All three of the things you are looking for are done using the TOC Field

Different switches control what is shown. *(TOC and TOF styles control how it looks.)*

Here is my writing on the [Table of Contents](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/complex_documents.htm#Table%20of%20Contents) and [Table of Figures](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/complex_documents.htm#TableFigures). Here is Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill's excellent article on [TOC Tips and Tricks](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TOCTips.htm).

When you post back with more information, I will give more specific direction. Please edit your question with the following information:

- Exact field that you are using. You can see this by toggling display of field codes. (Alt+F9 or Fn+Alt+F9 in Windows) [Dealing with Fields](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/dealing-with-fields-in-microsoft-word/e1bdddad-5a51-4327-837c-c3786c16a501) (my article)
- Are you using the [Caption feature](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/complex_documents.htm#Caption) in Word to identify your Figures and Tables? This works with the Table of Figures/Table of Captions.
- What is your operating system? Windows? Mac? Version?